# Unidentified 80s Commodore Game manual font

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

Does anyone know what font is used in this commodore game manual?

[image]

I found it in a web archive collection https://archive.org/details/Commodore_64_Game_Manual_Collection on archive. org

It's kind of an blunt extended geometric lineal. It seems to be used in several 80s COMMODORE manuals, such as Dragon Lair, Bomb Jack II, maybe it is part of a default template.

The uppercase 'A' appears condensed while the other uppercase glyphs are extended. Notice how dark the 'M' is. At first I thought of an akzidenz grotesk because of the large leg of the 'R' but the condensed 'A' does not fit at all.

Comment: At that time - mid 80s - there were typewriters with proportional fonts. The type is wonky enough, and with faux bold to boot, to have been created with such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bold text looks like it's AG Book Medium Extended:

[image]

It also looks like AG Book Regular Extended was used for the the body "header" text and AG Book Regular was used for the main paragraphs and supplementary text.

[image]

NOTE: I compared them using the Std variant supplied from https://www.bertholdtypes.com but I think the comparison is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ovaryraptor and usr2564301

I suppose that due to typewriting (or an another technical constrain), they probably have to used only one family (glyphs limitation).

But they also wanted to produce a strong visual contrast between titles and paragraphs.

So they remplaced AG Book Regular uppercases with AG Book Extended uppercases.
Notice that titles are always in uppercase.
(with false bold)

But

also they decided to not remplace all uppercases with an extended version ( like the 'A', the 'J' and maybe more ) for aesthetical reasons ( or maybe they forgot some )